# Flask-Admin: sort column by different field

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm trying to control the sorting of a model list in Flask-Admin, and I'm a little confused about how `column_sortable_list` works. (I believe that's what I should be using.)

In my case, I have two columns of interest: "word", a text column, and "created", a timestamp. The catch is, I want "word" to be sorted on a separate database field (in the same table), "sortable_word", which is a version of "word" regularized to lowercase, with accented characters replaced by their non-accented versions, all non-[a-z] characters stripped out, etc.

The docs say "If you want to explicitly specify field/column to be used while sorting, you can use a tuple", and shows the example `column_sortable_list = ('name', ('user', 'user.username'))`, but either the example isn't right, or I don't understand the format.

For me, `column_sortable_list = ('word', ('word', 'sortable_word'))` doesn't work; "word" is sorted based on "word" only. Using `('word', ('word', 'sortable_word'), 'created')` fails in the same way, though also sorts by "created" (correctly). If I use `(('word', 'sortable_word'), 'created')`, then only "created" is sortable.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your columns as follows:

```
# Only sorting on one column
column_sortable_list = (('word', ('sortable_word', )), )

# multiple sort columns
column_sortable_list = (('word', ('sortable_word', )), 'created')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use brackets like this , however I'm having trouble finding this in the documentation...

```
column_sortable_list =  [
    'word',
    'created'
    ]
```

Comment: `column_sortable_list` is documented in the Base Model View docs, at https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView. That shows the use of parens; switching to brackets doesn't affect my results. Your example shows sorting by two different columns, which isn't my issue--that already works for me.

Comment: Oops I forgot to add the sortable_word column in my answer. I'm assuming this is an existing column in your model?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I can, for example, have `column_default_sort = 'sortable_word'` and this works fine for the initial list, so I know it works as far as the model is concerned; the question is how to get `word` to sort based on `sortable_word`.

Comment: I understand now. Not sure if this is supported by flask admin though. I'm going to test this myself :)

Comment: Thank you. An additional question might be "What does 'If you want to explicitly specify field/column to be used while sorting, you can use a tuple' mean in the docs?" If I were better at Python I could presumably figure it out from the source, but I'm not.